# Need a user input to be one of three valid answers. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project for school and I am struggling to get validation working. I am working on a Maths Quiz which stores scores in different text files. Problem I have is, that when the quiz asks for the Student's name and class, the class needs to be one of three classes. Class 1, 2 or 3.

If a student inputs an invalid class, it must ask for the class again until they input a valid class name. Any idea how I would make it ask the question until it gets a valid answer then run a bunch of code?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried so far to solve this. Also an example of expected input along with the desired actions for that input would be very helpful.

Comment: Hey Scott, can you provide some code you tried, please? Like, how are you trying to get the value? How does this input look like, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
a=None

while a not in ('1','2','3'):

    a=input('?')
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` loops.

```
valid_classes = (1, 2, 3)

class_num = 0
while class_num not in valid_classes:
    try:
        class_num = int(input("Please enter a class number from {}:".format(valid_classes)))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```